# c++のnamespaceについて

Tags: c++

下記のコードで次のようなエラーが出ます。

Aの名前空間でBの変数を使用しているのですが、認識されません。
どのようにすれば解決するでしょうか？
解決策が分かる方はよろしくお願いいたします。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
namespace.cpp: In function ‘void A::Func()’:
namespace.cpp: error: ‘B’ has not been declared
std::cout << B::y << std::endl;
```

**ソースコード**

```
#include<iostream>
namespace A{
 int x;
 void Func(){
  std::cout << B::y << std::endl;
 }
};
namespace B{
 int y;
 void Func(){
  std::cout << A::x << std::endl;
 }
};
int main(){
 A::x = 2;
 B::y = 5;
 A::Func();
 B::Func();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++のコンパイラは、上からコードを解析していくので、関数や変数の名前は、使う前に宣言しなければなりません。なので、先に宣言しましょう。

```
namespace B{
 int y; // 先に定義しておく
}

namespace A{
 int x;
 void Func(){
  std::cout << B::y << std::endl;
 }
};
namespace B{
// int y; <- ここのは不要
 void Func(){
  std::cout << A::x << std::endl;
 }
};
```

こんな方法もあります。

```
namespace B{
 extern int y; // 名前だけ宣言
}

namespace A{
 int x;
 void Func(){
  std::cout << B::y << std::endl;
 }
};
namespace B{
 int y; // 実体は、ここで定義
 void Func(){
  std::cout << A::x << std::endl;
 }
};
```